# Why is she using "for" instead of "to" after the verb "lose" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions

I'm watching the famous TV show, “Desperate Housewives”. 
I have learned a plethora of words and grammar things from it,
but now something caught my ears and I'm a bit stuck. 
There's this sentence in season 2, episode 6:

> "-My friends just left, and I was hoping you could come over and cut me out of this thing [dress]. "
>   "-How was your little reunion?"
>    "-It was, um -- weird." 
>   -"Weird?" 
>   -"Well, Allison's mad because she's losing jobs **for** 14-year-olds, Holly is on a strict diet of cruciferous vegetables, and Yazmin is undergoing a new embryonic facial treatment that probably causes short-term-memory loss. I just stood there the whole night, trying to remember why we were ever friends. And I couldn't"

My question is, should it not be **to** instead of **for** in the above dialogue? I've googled it already, and I found only examples that bolster my assumption.

Dear natives, please enlighten me why **for** is used here.

Comment: Not a native, but most prepositions are fixed combinations, and most of them stick to English usage, making them sound idiomatic.

Comment: We need the context.  Is she an employer who wanted to hire 14 year-olds but now cannot? Or was she competing for a job against a 14 year-old who ended up getting the job instead of her?

Comment: "-My friends just left, and I was hoping you could come over and cut me out of this thing [dress]. "
"-How was your little reunion?"
 "-It was, um -- weird." 
-"Weird?" 
-"Well, Allison's mad because she's losing jobs for 14-year-olds, Holly is on a strict diet of cruciferous vegetables, and Yazmin is undergoing a new embryonic facial treatment that probably causes short-term-memory loss. I just stood there the whole night, trying to remember why we were ever friends. And I couldn't"

Comment: "... she's losing jobs [that are intended] for 14-year-olds." A few words are left out because they are immediately understandable (for native speakers).

Comment: Thank you Robusto! I thought the speaker was insinuating that her friend
(Allsion) was not getting the job because 14-year-olds took over her place (in the modelling industry) . Like a cheetah loses prey to lions, she was losing the competition of getting the job to younger, new models. ( the 14-year-olds.) I mean that's what I thought she meant.

Comment: I don't agree with Robusto here. The preposition *for* is often used to denote a beneficiary - someone who gains from something, or to indicate a meaning similar to *because*, or to indicate a replacement of some sort (I swapped apples for oranges). I think one of these two is the reason *for* is  used here.

Comment: @Araucaria: That's a stretch. Possible, but not likely.

Comment: The statement is still ambiguous. It could be saying that she's taking jobs away from 14-year-olds, that 14-year-olds are getting jobs instead of her, or that she's failing to get jobs that are meant to be handled by 14-year-olds. We don't know who any of these people are or what the larger context is.